# When I change stdin to raw mode, stdout is affected... why?

Tags: linux, stdin

I have a Linux program that I need to change stdin to raw mode.  I use this code:

```
 if (isatty(STDIN_FILENO)) {
        if (tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO,&tiostdin) != 0) {
            perror("tcgetattr stdin");
            close(ttyfd);
            exit(1);
        }
        // cfmakeraw() puts stdin in 'raw' mode, which includes
        // turning off the ctrl-c interrupt...
        cfmakeraw(&tiostdin);
        if (tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSAFLUSH, &tiostdin) != 0) {
            perror("tcsetattr stdin");
            close(ttyfd);
            exit(1);
        }
    }
```

After that point, any printf with "\n" no longer inserts "\r".
Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Because that's what the man page says it does.  https://linux.die.net/man/3/cfmakeraw.

Comment: Yea, I guess I stopped reading after "raw" mode... Replacing cfmakeraw() with the individual flag modifications, but omitting c_oflag appears to solve my problem.  Tx